# Remove files from GDrive Trash

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, recycle-bin

I have backup scripts that are copying my files into GDrive and it's also deleting files that are older than X days. But this is filling my bin with lot of these files. I want to remove them from trash bin.

I wrote this code:

```
function getTrashedFiles() {
  //find every file in bin
  var trashedSearch = DriveApp.searchFiles('trashed=true');
  while (trashedSearch.hasNext()) {
    var file = trashedSearch.next();
    if (file.getName().indexOf("DBKLP") >= 0) {
      //this is correctly printing files that I want to remove
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      //this should remove from bin
      DriveApp.removeFile(file);
    }
  }
}
```

This code correctly finds every file, that starts at "DBKLP". But when it runs, it's not removing files from bin. It's just removing them 'once again', so their date of remove is basically "now".

**I can't find a way to "remove from bin".**

Comment: When your issue has not been resolved and you still want the solution, can I ask you about your current issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removefilechild): removeFile(child) does not delete the file, but if a file is removed from all of its parents, it cannot be seen in Drive except by searching for it or using the "All items" view.

Have you tried [`Drive.Files.remove()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/#Files) instead of `DriveApp.removeFile()`?
To enable it, in the script editor, you have to click on the + button at "Services". Check here: imgur.com/cVFCAXQ (or, in the old editor navigate to Resources > Advanced Google Services > Drive API).

I have a similar script that seems to work. Notice that it has to find all files *and* folders because they are treated separately.

```
// Delete all files from trash older than 1 month
function cleanOldTrash() {
  var files = DriveApp.getTrashedFiles();
  var folders = DriveApp.getTrashedFolders();
 
  var lastMonth = new Date();
  lastMonth.setDate(lastMonth.getDate() - 30);
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getLastUpdated() < lastMonth ) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
    }
  }
  
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    if (folder.getLastUpdated() < lastMonth) {
     Drive.Files.remove(folder.getId());
  }
}
}
```

I actually do have a problem with this script when files are stored on the trash of Team Drives that I don't have permission to access, but I'll try to get more help with that in a separate question. I'll update this answer if needed.

Comment: Hello. "TypeError: DriveApp.remove is not a function" and while using Drive.Files.Remove I got "ReferenceError: Drive is not defined". But you made me realize that I'm deleting files that are not from my folder, it's just shared folder. But I'm still trying to delete it from my trash bin.

Comment: @ĽubošCsonka  I think you need to enable the Drive API v3 manually. Navigate to Resources > Advanced Google Services > Drive API and enable it. Let me know if it works. I changed the answer with some information abou why you have to do that.

Comment: `Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());` on this line, it says Drive is undefined. Drive API is enabled for me. Because all the DriveApp calls are working fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, getLastUpdated is not the date the file was binned/trashed, but just when the file was last modified (before it was binned/trashed). There's no way to get the binned date through the API (only in the UI sort by date column)

Comment: @AdilMalik in the new editor, you have to enable it by clicking in + at "Services". Check here: https://imgur.com/cVFCAXQ

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja That's true. In my case I was most worried about the file last update. Maybe you can hack arround it by modifying the file slightly when you move it to trash?

Answer (score 0):

The AppScript `DriveApp` does not support it, but you can do it with the Drive API v3. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) states, you'd need to use the `DELETE` HTTP method; alike this you could even skip trashing these files altogether. Here's an [example](https://github.com/syslogic/google-apps-script/blob/master/cloud-datastore/CloudDatastore.gs) (mine) of how to use Google API with AppScript (that's another API, but at least it's a good starting point). The documentation combined with a rough example should hopefully push you into the right direction.